# RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-code

Whe i try to push i have this error

```
user1@cloudshell:~/app-web-2 (in-210216)$ git add *

user1@cloudshell:~/app-web-2 (in-210216)$ git commit -m "space"
[master c0f7b55] space
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
user1@cloudshell:~/app-web-2 (in-210216)$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 346 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)


error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
</b>
Everything up-to-date
user1@cloudshell:~/app-web-2 (in-210216)$
```

i try : git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

but still not push !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I just found the solution you have to pay all the bill google cloud.